# How do I open a list of txt files, convert them to strings, and then see if they match any keys from a given dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension, ordereddictionary, string-search

I have a list of text files (list_4), of the format cv1.txt, cv2.txt, cv3.txt etc, up to cv20.txt. I want to use a for loop to open and read these files indivdually and convert them into strings. This is my code:

```
list_5 = []
for i in list_4:
    file = open(i)
    line = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    list_5.append(line)
    file.close()
print(list_5)
```

This part of the code works to open, read, and convert to strings my list_4 of txt files.

Now I have a dictionary called my_dict, of the format {'abandoned':-1, "abandonment':1, 'abandon':0......}

I want to use a for loop to compare the previously generated string elements from list_5 against the key pairs of my_dict, to output a series of integers for each string element of list_4.

For example:

```
for key in my_dict:
    for i in list_4:
        file = open(i, 'r')
        line = file.read()
        file.close()
        if key in line:
            list_6.append(my_dict[key])
print(list_6)
```

however the issue is that the output of this for loop is a series of jumbled keys and files:

```
['-1cv1.txt', '-1cv8.txt', '-1cv17.txt', '1cv4.txt', '1cv6.txt', '1cv1.txt', ...]
```

obtained using:

```
for key in my_dict:
    for i in list_4:
        file = open(i, 'r')
        line = file.read()
        file.close()
        if key in line:
            list_6.append(str(my_dict[key]) + i)
print(list_6)
```

Is there any way for me to get the keys specific to each string element in list_5 i.e.

list_5: ['the cow goes moo', 'the cat goes meow',...]
list_6: [[0,1,-1],[0,0,0],...]

might need to use a list within a list? not sure, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please list your code in the correct format. For more information please click on the help section on the section where you wrote the question.

Comment: just fixed, sorry about that

Comment: Ok, thank you that makes it easier for us to read. I've removed my downvote.

Comment: Your loops are in a rather unhelpful order - by having the loop over files _inside_ the loop over your dictionary keys, you are having to read each file multiple times unnecessarily.

Comment: @alaniwi I tried to use a nested for loop but was unable to generate an output, i am not too experienced with these.

Comment: Please can you clarify exactly what the `[0,1,-1]` and `[0,0,0]` in your example correspond to.

Comment: @alaniwi, those are the values from the dictionary, where if the string includes a "key" that is also in the dictionary, than the value is printed out. For instance if the dictionary is {"cow":-1}, and the string is "the cow goes moo", then the value, -1 is printed for that string.

Comment: @AndrewLittle1 So to test my understanding... although there happen to be the same number of elements in each of these sub-lists in this example, in principle they could be different lengths if the strings had different numbers of matching words, and the `[0,1,-1]` corresponds to the string `'the cow goes moo'` while `[0,0,0]` corresponds to `'the cat goes meow'`, e.g. if you had `{'the':0, 'meow':0, 'moo':1, 'cat': 0, 'cow':-1}` - is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct, list_4 has 20 elements, each txt file corresponding to an element in that list, each element is a string. The dictionary my_dict, has about 3,000 entries, and i want to see if there are any matches between the dictionary and the elements in list_4

Comment: Please give a *complete* example - enough information so that someone else can run the code (and create the initial file contents) and observe the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, you'd like your final output to look something like this:

```
[ ( 'the cow goes moo', [0, 1, -1] ), ( 'the cat goes meow', [0, 0, 0]),... ]
```

If so, maybe try:

```
for line in list_5: # using list_5 instead of list_4
    sub_list = []
    for key in my_dict:
        if key in line:
            sub_list.append(my_dict[key])
    list_6.append(sub_list)
combined = list( zip( list_5, list_6 ))
print( combined )
```

(If all the `line` items are really whitespace delimited, the script can be sped up by splitting each `line` and iterating over that rather than the dictionary keys, but ignoring that for now...)
Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: This worked, thanks for your help @mark_s!